# Standard process suddenly throwing ORA-02270 error

Tags: sql, oracle, key, primary-key, toad

I have a series of SQL scripts inherited form a coworker that I run a few times a year, for couple years now. This time, I'm having an error I've never seen before. The code is below:

```
    /* First drop and then create table scbcrse_xref */
    DROP TABLE ddef_stag.SCBCRSE_XREF;
    CREATE TABLE ddef_stag.SCBCRSE_XREF AS SELECT
    ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_term_code,
    ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_crn,
    ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_subj_code,
    ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_crse_numb,
    MAX(ddef_stag.SCBCRSE.scbcrse_eff_term) "SCBCRSE_MAX_EFF_TERM"
    FROM ddef_stag.SCBCRSE, ddef_stag.SSBSECT
    WHERE ddef_stag.SCBCRSE.scbcrse_subj_code = ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_subj_code  AND 
          ddef_stag.SCBCRSE.scbcrse_crse_numb = ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_crse_numb  AND
          ddef_stag.SCBCRSE.scbcrse_eff_term <= ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_term_code  
    GROUP BY ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_term_code, ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_crn,
 ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_subj_code, ddef_stag.SSBSECT.ssbsect_crse_numb;
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* Add foreign key constraint on scbcrse_xref */
    ALTER TABLE ddef_stag.SCBCRSE_XREF ADD 
    CONSTRAINT SCBCRSE_XREF_SSBSECT_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (ssbsect_term_code, ssbsect_crn)
    REFERENCES  SSBSECT(ssbsect_term_code, ssbsect_crn);
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /* Add foreign key constraint on scbcrse_xref */

    ALTER TABLE ddef_stag.SCBCRSE_XREF ADD 
    CONSTRAINT SCBCRSE_XREF_SCBCRSE_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (ssbsect_subj_code, ssbsect_crse_numb, scbcrse_max_eff_term)
    REFERENCES  SCBCRSE (scbcrse_subj_code, scbcrse_crse_numb, scbcrse_eff_term);
```

Both foreign key constraints give the error:
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Looking at the table information for SCBCRSE and SSBSECT, they look like they have the proper primary key enabled. I've looked at both SCBCRSE and SSBSECT, and there's no obvious issues in the joins between those two tables. What is going wrong? What else can I check?

Edit: I've been asked to post a describe() of the tables involved:

```
describe scbcrse
TABLE scbcrse
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SCBCRSE_SUBJ_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)                
 SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                
 SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(24)                
 SCBCRSE_COLL_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_DIVS_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(16)                
 SCBCRSE_DEPT_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(16)                
 SCBCRSE_CSTA_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_TITLE                                      VARCHAR2(120)               
 SCBCRSE_CIPC_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(24)                
 SCBCRSE_CREDIT_HR_IND                              VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_CREDIT_HR_LOW                              NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_CREDIT_HR_HIGH                             NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_LEC_HR_IND                                 VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_LEC_HR_LOW                                 NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_LEC_HR_HIGH                                NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_LAB_HR_IND                                 VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_LAB_HR_LOW                                 NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_LAB_HR_HIGH                                NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_OTH_HR_IND                                 VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_OTH_HR_LOW                                 NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_OTH_HR_HIGH                                NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_BILL_HR_IND                                VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_BILL_HR_LOW                                NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_BILL_HR_HIGH                               NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_APRV_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_REPEAT_LIMIT                               NUMBER(2)                   
 SCBCRSE_PWAV_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_TUIW_IND                                   VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_ADD_FEES_IND                               VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_ACTIVITY_DATE                              DATE                        
 SCBCRSE_CONT_HR_LOW                                NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_CONT_HR_IND                                VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_CONT_HR_HIGH                               NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_CEU_IND                                    VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_REPS_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SCBCRSE_MAX_RPT_UNITS                              NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SCBCRSE_CAPP_PREREQ_TEST_IND              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_DUNT_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(16)                
 SCBCRSE_NUMBER_OF_UNITS                            NUMBER(7,2)                 
 SCBCRSE_DATA_ORIGIN                                VARCHAR2(120)               
 SCBCRSE_USER_ID                                    VARCHAR2(120)               
 SCBCRSE_PREREQ_CHK_METHOD_CDE             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SCBCRSE_SURROGATE_ID                               NUMBER(19)                  
 SCBCRSE_VERSION                                    NUMBER(19)                  
 SCBCRSE_VPDI_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(24)                

describe ssbsect
TABLE ssbsect
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SSBSECT_TERM_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(24)                
 SSBSECT_CRN                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                
 SSBSECT_PTRM_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(12)                
 SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)                
 SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                
 SSBSECT_SEQ_NUMB                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)                
 SSBSECT_SSTS_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_SCHD_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)                
 SSBSECT_CAMP_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(12)                
 SSBSECT_CRSE_TITLE                                 VARCHAR2(120)               
 SSBSECT_CREDIT_HRS                                 NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SSBSECT_BILL_HRS                                   NUMBER(7,3)                 
 SSBSECT_GMOD_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_SAPR_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SSBSECT_SESS_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_LINK_IDENT                                 VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SSBSECT_PRNT_IND                                   VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_GRADABLE_IND                               VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_TUIW_IND                                   VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_REG_ONEUP                         NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_PRIOR_ENRL                        NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_PROJ_ENRL                         NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_MAX_ENRL                          NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_ENRL                              NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_SEATS_AVAIL                       NOT NULL NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_TOT_CREDIT_HRS                             NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SSBSECT_CENSUS_ENRL                                NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_CENSUS_ENRL_DATE                  NOT NULL DATE                        
 SSBSECT_ACTIVITY_DATE                     NOT NULL DATE                        
 SSBSECT_PTRM_START_DATE                            DATE                        
 SSBSECT_PTRM_END_DATE                              DATE                        
 SSBSECT_PTRM_WEEKS                                 NUMBER(3)                   
 SSBSECT_RESERVED_IND                               VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_WAIT_CAPACITY                              NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_WAIT_COUNT                                 NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_WAIT_AVAIL                                 NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_LEC_HR                                     NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SSBSECT_LAB_HR                                     NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SSBSECT_OTH_HR                                     NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SSBSECT_CONT_HR                                    NUMBER(9,3)                 
 SSBSECT_ACCT_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SSBSECT_ACCL_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(8)                 
 SSBSECT_CENSUS_2_DATE                              DATE                        
 SSBSECT_ENRL_CUT_OFF_DATE                          DATE                        
 SSBSECT_ACAD_CUT_OFF_DATE                          DATE                        
 SSBSECT_DROP_CUT_OFF_DATE                          DATE                        
 SSBSECT_CENSUS_2_ENRL                              NUMBER(4)                   
 SSBSECT_VOICE_AVAIL                       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_CAPP_PREREQ_TEST_IND              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_GSCH_NAME                                  VARCHAR2(40)                
 SSBSECT_BEST_OF_COMP                               NUMBER(3)                   
 SSBSECT_SUBSET_OF_COMP                             NUMBER(3)                   
 SSBSECT_INSM_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(20)                
 SSBSECT_REG_FROM_DATE                              DATE                        
 SSBSECT_REG_TO_DATE                                DATE                        
 SSBSECT_LEARNER_REGSTART_FDATE                     DATE                        
 SSBSECT_LEARNER_REGSTART_TDATE                     DATE                        
 SSBSECT_DUNT_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(16)                
 SSBSECT_NUMBER_OF_UNITS                            NUMBER(7,2)                 
 SSBSECT_NUMBER_OF_EXTENSIONS              NOT NULL NUMBER(3)                   
 SSBSECT_DATA_ORIGIN                                VARCHAR2(120)               
 SSBSECT_USER_ID                                    VARCHAR2(120)               
 SSBSECT_INTG_CDE                                   VARCHAR2(20)                
 SSBSECT_PREREQ_CHK_METHOD_CDE                      VARCHAR2(4)                 
 SSBSECT_SURROGATE_ID                               NUMBER(19)                  
 SSBSECT_VERSION                                    NUMBER(19)                  
 SSBSECT_VPDI_CODE                                  VARCHAR2(24)                
 SSBSECT_KEYWORD_INDEX_ID                           VARCHAR2(120)               

describe SCBCRSE_XREF

TABLE SCBCRSE_XREF
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SSBSECT_TERM_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(24)                
 SSBSECT_CRN                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                
 SSBSECT_SUBJ_CODE                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(16)                
 SSBSECT_CRSE_NUMB                         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)                
 SCBCRSE_MAX_EFF_TERM                               VARCHAR2(24)
```

Comment: It isn't an answer but if you would `TRUNCATE` the table instead of dropping it, you would not need to recreate it and would not need to recreate the foreign keys.  Aside from that, I would suggest you post a `DESCRIBE` from each of the tables.

Comment: To me, it sounds like the result of a long running query got corrupted by other threads that modified the related table data. That is, the FKs are not available anymore. I would decouple the `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT...` into: 1) `CREATE TABLE x (col1, col2, fk1, fk2, etc.)` and 2) `INSERT INTO x SELECT ...`. The FKs will be enforced while the insert is running, and then you'll see **other** processes crashing :D

Comment: I've added the describe() information to the tables. @the-impaler, I'll see about trying that out.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with our DBA and found out that the constraints for SSBSECT and SCBCRSE were not properly enabled. Enabling them solved the problem.

Comment: So, either these scripts which you inherited never worked or somebody changed them. Still, this is a testament to talking to ones co-workers rather than asking a bunch of strangers on the internet. Talking is good! Let's do more of it!

Comment: What changed is that the DBA does a transfer of tables from one server to another. They must have turned off the primary keys but didn't re-enable them.